# ERROR al instalar react, no sale la carpeta pages

Tags: reactjs

Al instalar REACT, con `npx create-next-app project` o se descarga la carpeta pages, he probado a arreglarlo instalando la versión más reciente de `next.js`

```
npm install -g next
```

Actualizando el `npm` con

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de la versión 13.4 de Next, ya no se usa la carpeta `pages`. En su lugar, todo va en la carpeta `app` y usa lo que llama el [App router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#the-app-router).

En [esta página de su blog](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4#nextjs-app-router) explican con  más detalle los motivos de este cambio.